# Why is perl executing backtick command before rendering and file creation is done?

Tags: perl, mason

I'm trying to render a file using a utility template in a Mason template (using an ancient CMS Bricolage).   That may not be important.

The $m->scomp should end up with a nicely composed json file which I then manually create, print to and close:

```
 my  $article_body = $m->scomp('/util/render_apple_story.mc');
 open my $fh, '>', $articlerootjson;
  print {$fh} $article_body . "\n";
    close $fh;
```

Then I try to execute a process that detects that file (with Python) and sends it to Apple

```perl
$output = `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 /var/home/tyee/PyAppleAPI/create_article.py https://news-api.apple.com $channel $key $secret $articleroot`; 
 print "return is $output \n";
```

But each FIRST time i execute the template, it fails to create the file.

And yet it runs the command in the backticks, which returns that there is no json file.

So somehow the perl program is continuing to step through either while the $m->scomp or file open/close commands are still in motion, and then exiting before the file can even be created.

The SECOND time through, if I rerender the template(re-run the perl)  the file will be created.

What gives? Is there some way of running the backtick portion ONLY if  the $m->scomp and file open + close have completed ?

Comment: Can you give enough of the mason context to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ysth here is the whole template with sensitive things changed to "hidden".  https://pastebin.com/cqixmXmn

Comment: "_somehow the perl program is continuing..._" -- you never check nor tell it what to do on failure?  It's the standard practice to check all IO (well, and more -- anything that goes out), `open my $fh, '>', $articlerootjson  or die "Can't open $articlerootjson: $!";`.  Then you'll see if `open` failed and why (that's `$!`).  I don't know what`scomp` is or how it works but if it doesn't report errors then check `$article_body` yourself (whether it's undefined or empty string).

Comment: "_Is there some way of running the backtick portion ONLY if ,,,_" -- Explicitly check the success of previous operations, as in the above comment

Comment: Btw -- I have no idea what that Python command does but I notice that it runs with `$articleroot` file while you write the file `$articlerootjson` (different name)

Comment: Thanks all, it couldn't open the file because the directory structure up to where the template outputs too did not yet exist. After previewing the first time, it is created by the template itself. Yes that would have shown me the error and saved me time,  @zdim thank you

Comment: @MrBryan Alright, great that you resolved it.  And absorb the moral of this: you _always_ want to check all calls "out" of your program; indeed you _must_ check.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the directory structure up to where the story uri was didn't yet exist.  I tried all kinds of forced previewing of output channels to no avail.

So after looking at shortcuts to create entire directory structures to a path, I had to do the inelegant:

```
my $year = $story->get_cover_date("%Y");
my $month = $story->get_cover_date("%m");
my $day = $story->get_cover_date("%d");
my $slug = $story->get_slug;

mkdir "/var/home/hidden/PyAppleAPI/root${caturi}${year}";
mkdir "/var/home/hidden/PyAppleAPI/root${caturi}${year}/${month}";
mkdir "/var/home/hidden/PyAppleAPI/root${caturi}${year}/${month}/${day}";
mkdir "/var/home/hidden/PyAppleAPI/root${caturi}${year}/${month}/${day}/${slug}";


my $status = `touch $articlerootjson`;
```

And then it let me open the file.  Opening the file with error reporting would have helped me I somehow did not think that was the step that was failing so I overlooked it.

Comment: The core library `File::Path` provides [make_path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Path#make_path(-$dir1,-$dir2,-....,-%5C%25opts-)) which makes whole directory hierarchies. So you only need `make_path( "/var/.../$slug")`. Possibly with options that are provided, see docs -- and figure out how you want the call checked.

Comment: Or `my ($year, $month, $day) = map { $story->get_cover_date($_) } qw(%Y %m %d);` (nothing's wrong with separate statements like you show, but you often really want [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map).

Comment: Then, if you were so inclined, can form the whole path in one statement: `my $path = "/var/.../root$caturi" . join '/', ( map { $story->get_cover_date($_) } qw(%Y %m %d) ), $story->get_slug;` (or even have this right inside `make_path` so w/o an extra variable `$path`)